# Active Directory and Apple's Workgroup Manager

Tags: active-directory, ldap, mac, workgroup, schema

I thought I'd share my experiences here. I work for a small business with only ~20 users. I wanted the ability to use managed client preferences to assign things like the software update server. Basically the ability to manage my Macs easily and in a native way.

At first I tried the magic triangle solution, but I found this to be very complicated. Not only does it require a Mac OS X Server, but it gives you two points of failure. Additionally each Mac workstation must be bound to both servers.

Eventually I sucked it up and went with the schema changes documented [here](http://images.apple.com/business/solutions/it/docs/Modifying_the_Active_Directory_Schema.pdf). I was hesitant at first, because the instructions require *a lot* of manual work. However it was fairly basic and only took me about an hour and a half. Below you'll find the schema changes file that was a result of my work. I followed the instructions exactly and double checked everything, after six months of having this in place things have been running great. Too good to not share. I hope I save someone a couple of hours.

```
# ==================================================================
#
#  This file should be imported with the following command:
#    ldifde -i -u -f Apple AD Schema Changes.ldf -s server:port -b username domain password -j . -c "cn=Configuration,dc=X" #configurationNamingContext
#  LDIFDE.EXE from AD/AM V1.0 or above must be used.
#  This LDIF file should be imported into AD or AD/AM. It may not work for other directories.
#
# ==================================================================

# ==================================================================
#  Attributes
# ==================================================================

# Attribute: apple-category
dn: cn=apple-category,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.10.4
ldapDisplayName: apple-category
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: Category for the computer or neighborhood
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-computeralias
dn: cn=apple-computeralias,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.20.3
ldapDisplayName: apple-computeralias
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: XML plist referring to a computer record
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-computer-list-groups
dn: cn=apple-computer-list-groups,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.11.4
ldapDisplayName: apple-computer-list-groups
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: groups
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-computers
dn: cn=apple-computers,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.11.3
ldapDisplayName: apple-computers
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: computers
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-data-stamp
dn: cn=apple-data-stamp,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.12.2
ldapDisplayName: apple-data-stamp
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: data stamp
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-dns-domain
dn: cn=apple-dns-domain,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.18.1
ldapDisplayName: apple-dns-domain
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: DNS domain
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-dnsname
dn: cn=apple-dnsname,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.4
ldapDisplayName: apple-dnsname
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: DNS name
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-dns-nameserver
dn: cn=apple-dns-nameserver,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.18.2
ldapDisplayName: apple-dns-nameserver
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: DNS name server list
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-group-homeowner
dn: cn=apple-group-homeowner,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.14.2
ldapDisplayName: apple-group-homeowner
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: group home owner settings
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-group-homeurl
dn: cn=apple-group-homeurl,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.14.1
ldapDisplayName: apple-group-homeurl
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: group home url
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-imhandle
dn: cn=apple-imhandle,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.21
ldapDisplayName: apple-imhandle
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: IM handle (service:account name)
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-keyword
dn: cn=apple-keyword,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.19
ldapDisplayName: apple-keyword
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: keywords
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-mcxflags
dn: cn=apple-mcxflags,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.10
ldapDisplayName: apple-mcxflags
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: mcx flags
oMSyntax: 64
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-mcxsettings
dn: cn=apple-mcxsettings,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.16
ldapDisplayName: apple-mcxsettings
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: mcx settings
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-neighborhoodalias
dn: cn=apple-neighborhoodalias,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.20.2
ldapDisplayName: apple-neighborhoodalias
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: XML plist referring to another neighborhood record
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-networkview
dn: cn=apple-networkview,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.10.3
ldapDisplayName: apple-networkview
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: Network view for the computer
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-nodepathxml
dn: cn=apple-nodepathxml,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.20.1
ldapDisplayName: apple-nodepathxml
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: XML plist of directory node path
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-service-location
dn: cn=apple-service-location,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.5
ldapDisplayName: apple-service-location
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: Service location
oMSyntax: 64
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-service-port
dn: cn=apple-service-port,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.3
ldapDisplayName: apple-service-port
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.9
adminDescription: Service port number
oMSyntax: 2
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-service-type
dn: cn=apple-service-type,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.1
ldapDisplayName: apple-service-type
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: type of service
oMSyntax: 22
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-service-url
dn: cn=apple-service-url,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.2
ldapDisplayName: apple-service-url
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: URL of service
oMSyntax: 22
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-user-authenticationhint
dn: cn=apple-user-authenticationhint,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.15
ldapDisplayName: apple-user-authenticationhint
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: password hint
oMSyntax: 64
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-user-class
dn: cn=apple-user-class,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.7
ldapDisplayName: apple-user-class
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: user class
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-user-homequota
dn: cn=apple-user-homequota,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.8
ldapDisplayName: apple-user-homequota
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: home directory quota
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-user-homesoftquota
dn: cn=apple-user-homesoftquota,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.17
ldapDisplayName: apple-user-homesoftquota
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: home directory soft quota
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-user-homeurl
dn: cn=apple-user-homeurl,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.6
ldapDisplayName: apple-user-homeurl
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: home directory URL
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-user-mailattribute
dn: cn=apple-user-mailattribute,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.9
ldapDisplayName: apple-user-mailattribute
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: mail attribute
oMSyntax: 64
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-user-picture
dn: cn=apple-user-picture,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.12
ldapDisplayName: apple-user-picture
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: picture
oMSyntax: 64
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-user-printattribute
dn: cn=apple-user-printattribute,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.13
ldapDisplayName: apple-user-printattribute
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: print attribute
oMSyntax: 64
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-webloguri
dn: cn=apple-webloguri,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.22
ldapDisplayName: apple-webloguri
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: Weblog URI
oMSyntax: 64
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: apple-xmlplist
dn: cn=apple-xmlplist,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.17.1
ldapDisplayName: apple-xmlplist
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: XML plist data
oMSyntax: 64
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: ipHostNumber
dn: cn=ipHostNumber,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.19
ldapDisplayName: ipHostNumber
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: IP address
oMSyntax: 22
systemOnly: FALSE
rangeUpper: 128

# Attribute: macAddress
dn: cn=macAddress,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.22
ldapDisplayName: macAddress
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: MAC address
oMSyntax: 22
systemOnly: FALSE
rangeUpper: 128

# Attribute: mountDirectory
dn: cn=apple-mountDirectory,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.1
ldapDisplayName: mountDirectory
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
adminDescription: mount path
oMSyntax: 64
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: mountDumpFrequency
dn: cn=apple-mountDumpFrequency,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.4
ldapDisplayName: mountDumpFrequency
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: mount dump frequency
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: mountOption
dn: cn=apple-mountOption,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.3
ldapDisplayName: mountOption
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: mount options
oMSyntax: 22
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: mountPassNo
dn: cn=apple-mountPassNo,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.5
ldapDisplayName: mountPassNo
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: mount passno
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: mountType
dn: cn=apple-mountType,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.2
ldapDisplayName: mountType
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.5
adminDescription: mount VFS type
oMSyntax: 22
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

# Attribute: ttl
dn: cn=ttl,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: attributeSchema
attributeId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.250.1.60
ldapDisplayName: ttl
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.9
oMSyntax: 2
isSingleValued: TRUE
systemOnly: FALSE

dn:
changetype: modify
add: schemaUpdateNow
schemaUpdateNow: 1
-


# ==================================================================
#  Classes
# ==================================================================

# Class: apple-computer
dn: cn=apple-computer,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.10
ldapDisplayName: apple-computer
adminDescription: computer
objectClassCategory: 3
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mayContain: apple-category
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.10.4
# mayContain: apple-computer-list-groups
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.11.4
# mayContain: apple-keyword
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.19
# mayContain: apple-mcxflags
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.10
# mayContain: apple-mcxsettings
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.16
# mayContain: apple-networkview
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.10.3
# mayContain: apple-service-url
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.2
# mayContain: apple-xmlplist
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.17.1
# mayContain: macAddress
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.22
# mayContain: ttl
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.250.1.60

# Class: apple-computer-list
dn: cn=apple-computer-list,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.11
ldapDisplayName: apple-computer-list
adminDescription: computer list
objectClassCategory: 1
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mayContain: apple-computer-list-groups
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.11.4
# mayContain: apple-computers
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.11.3
# mayContain: apple-keyword
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.19
# mayContain: apple-mcxflags
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.10
# mayContain: apple-mcxsettings
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.16
possSuperiors: organizationalUnit
possSuperiors: container

# Class: apple-configuration
dn: cn=apple-configuration,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.12
ldapDisplayName: apple-configuration
adminDescription: configuration
objectClassCategory: 3
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mayContain: apple-data-stamp
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.12.2
# mayContain: apple-keyword
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.19
# mayContain: apple-xmlplist
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.17.1
# mayContain: ttl
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.250.1.60
possSuperiors: organizationalUnit
possSuperiors: container

# Class: apple-group
dn: cn=apple-group,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.14
ldapDisplayName: apple-group
adminDescription: group account
objectClassCategory: 3
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mayContain: apple-group-homeowner
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.14.2
# mayContain: apple-group-homeurl
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.14.1
# mayContain: apple-keyword
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.19
# mayContain: apple-mcxflags
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.10
# mayContain: apple-mcxsettings
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.16
# mayContain: apple-user-picture
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.12
# mayContain: ttl
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.250.1.60

# Class: apple-location
dn: cn=apple-location,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.18
ldapDisplayName: apple-location
objectClassCategory: 1
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mayContain: apple-dns-domain
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.18.1
# mayContain: apple-dns-nameserver
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.18.2
possSuperiors: organizationalUnit
possSuperiors: container

# Class: apple-neighborhood
dn: cn=apple-neighborhood,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.20
ldapDisplayName: apple-neighborhood
objectClassCategory: 1
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mayContain: apple-category
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.10.4
# mayContain: apple-computeralias
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.20.3
# mayContain: apple-keyword
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.19
# mayContain: apple-neighborhoodalias
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.20.2
# mayContain: apple-nodepathxml
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.20.1
# mayContain: apple-xmlplist
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.17.1
# mayContain: ttl
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.250.1.60
possSuperiors: 2.5.6.5
possSuperiors: container

# Class: apple-serverassistant-config
dn: cn=apple-serverassistant-config,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.17
ldapDisplayName: apple-serverassistant-config
objectClassCategory: 1
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mayContain: apple-xmlplist
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.17.1
possSuperiors: organizationalUnit
possSuperiors: container

# Class: apple-service
dn: cn=apple-service,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.19
ldapDisplayName: apple-service
objectClassCategory: 1
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mustContain: apple-service-type
mustContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.1
# mayContain: apple-dnsname
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.4
# mayContain: apple-keyword
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.19
# mayContain: apple-service-location
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.5
# mayContain: apple-service-port
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.3
# mayContain: apple-service-url
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.19.2
# mayContain: ipHostNumber
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.19
possSuperiors: organizationalUnit
possSuperiors: container

# Class: apple-user
dn: cn=apple-user,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.1
ldapDisplayName: apple-user
adminDescription: apple user account
objectClassCategory: 3
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mayContain: apple-imhandle
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.21
# mayContain: apple-keyword
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.19
# mayContain: apple-mcxflags
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.10
# mayContain: apple-mcxsettings
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.16
# mayContain: apple-user-authenticationhint
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.15
# mayContain: apple-user-class
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.7
# mayContain: apple-user-homequota
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.8
# mayContain: apple-user-homesoftquota
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.17
# mayContain: apple-user-homeurl
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.6
# mayContain: apple-user-mailattribute
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.9
# mayContain: apple-user-picture
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.12
# mayContain: apple-user-printattribute
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.13
# mayContain: apple-webloguri
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.1.22

# Class: mount
dn: cn=apple-mount,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.2.8
ldapDisplayName: mount
objectClassCategory: 1
# subclassOf: top
subclassOf: 2.5.6.0
# rdnAttId: cn
rdnAttId: 2.5.4.3
# mayContain: mountDirectory
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.1
# mayContain: mountDumpFrequency
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.4
# mayContain: mountOption
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.3
# mayContain: mountPassNo
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.5
# mayContain: mountType
mayContain: 1.3.6.1.4.1.63.1000.1.1.1.8.2
possSuperiors: 2.5.6.5
possSuperiors: container    

dn:
changetype: modify
add: schemaUpdateNow
schemaUpdateNow: 1
-


# ==================================================================
#  Updating present elements
# ==================================================================
# Add the new class to the user object
dn: CN=User,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
changetype: modify
add: auxiliaryClass
auxiliaryClass: apple-user
-

# Add the new class to the computer object
dn: CN=Computer,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
changetype: modify
add: auxiliaryClass
auxiliaryClass: apple-computer
-

# Add the new class to the group object
dn: CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
changetype: modify
add: auxiliaryClass
auxiliaryClass: apple-group
-
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this... this should help alot of folks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this!

Apple professional services will also handle this for you. It took them 1 day to test the schema change, deploy the schema change to production, and train the administrators about the changes.  However APS (apple professional services) can get expensive! (depending on your company/city, could be as much as $2000/day)

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this!!! Great!

A little question though...

Uou have apple-configuration as an Auxilary Class (3), but in this video they mention only apple-user, apple-group and apple-computer to be Auxilary Classes.

There are also 39 attributes and the video specifies 36 attributes and 10 classes.

Should I worry about this?

The guide I was looking at is this one:
http://seminars.apple.com/seminarsonline/modifying/apple/index.html?s=301

Thanks!

/Brian